# Start from $259^2 + 1^2 = 34 \cdot 1973$ and use the descent procedure to write the prime 1973 as a sum of two squares.

Tags: number-theory

> Start from $259^2 + 1^2 = 34 \cdot 1973$ and use the descent procedure to write the prime 1973 as a sum of two squares.

How to solve it using fermat descent method?

Comment: but $2592+12=2604\ne 34\cdot 1973$

Comment: $\#4$ of http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~fcellaro/Francesco_Cellarosi_Home_Page/MATH_453_F12_files/hw14.pdf

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$259^2+1^2=34\cdot1973$$

$$34^2\cdot1973=(5^2+3^2)(259^2+1^2)$$

Use [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) and observe that $(259\cdot5-3\cdot1,259\cdot3+5\cdot1)=34$

Answer (score 1):

$34 \cdot 1973 = 259^2 + 1^2; \\ (21^2 + 1^2)(259^2 + 1^2)=(21 \cdot 259 +1)^2+(259-21)^2 \implies 13 \cdot 1973 = 7^2 + 160^2. $

$(7^2 + 4^2)(7^2 + 160^2)=(7 \cdot 7 +160 \cdot 4)^2+(160 \cdot 7-4 \cdot 7)^2 \implies 5 \cdot 1973 = 53^2 + 84^2. $

$(2^2 + 1^2)(53^2 + 84^2)=(2 \cdot 53 + 84 \cdot 1 )^2+(84 \cdot 2 -53 \cdot 1 )^2 \implies 1973 = 38^2 + 23^2.$