# It seems impossible to reduce $34 \cdot 1973 = 259^2 + 1^2$ to $1973 = a^2 + b^2$!

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples

The question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183726/start-from-2592-12-34-cdot-1973-and-use-the-descent-procedure-to-write/1183766). I know the method so hints in the comments/answers don't help. The problem is that the process stops from a point on! And it must not be so because the Descent Procedure guarantees otherwise...

$34 \cdot 1973 = 259^2 + 1^2; \\ (21^2 + 1^2)(259^2 + 1^2)=(21 \cdot 259 +1)^2+(259-21)^2 \implies 13 \cdot 1973 = 7^2 + 160^2. $ It's good because by the method must $13 \le 34/2$ as it is.

$(7^2 + 4^2)(7^2 + 160^2)=(7 \cdot 7 +160 \cdot 4)^2+(160 \cdot 7-4 \cdot 7)^2 \implies 5 \cdot 1973 = 53^2 + 84^2. $ Good again since $5 \le 13/2$.

$(3^2 + 4^2)(53^2 + 84^2)=(99 \cdot 5 )^2+(8 \cdot 5)^2 \implies 5 \cdot 1973 = 99^2 + 8^2.$ And $5 \le 5/2$ doesn't hold. Also from $5 \cdot 1973 = 99^2 + 8^2 \implies 5 \cdot 1973 = 53^2 + 84^2$ by the method! That famous circle of misfortune here!

Two problems here:

$1.$ It must always $m \le M/2$ as we go from $M \cdot p = A^2 + B^2$ to $m \cdot p = a^2 + b^2$. Why it can't be true in this case though it contradicts an existing theorem about it?

$2.$ Then how we arrive at [$1973 = 23^2 + 38^2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1973%20%3D%20a%5E2%2Bb%5E2) starting from $34 \cdot 1973 = 259^2 + 1^2$?

Added - Same problem occurs when trying to arrive at $96493 = 258^2 + 173^2$ starting from $10 \cdot 96493 = 261^2 + 947^2$!

Comment: I don't follow the procedure, but wouldn't the next step be $(3^2+1^2)$ rather than $(3^2+4^2)$ ?

Comment: @Michael, I found out where was the problem! After reducing mod M, new numbers must be in $[-M/2,M/2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want a procedure to write $1973$ as a sum of two squares using the facts that
$$
\begin{aligned}
2\cdot17\cdot1973&=259^2+1^2,\\
17&=4^2+1^2,\\
2&=1^2+1^2.
\end{aligned}
$$

I would also approach this using complex numbers, Gaussian integers $\Bbb{Z}[i]=\{a+bi, a,b\in\Bbb{Z}\}$, to be more precise. The idea is to use the multiplicativity of the norm function $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$. To a great extent the method depends on the fact that $N$ is a Euclidean norm of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ (If we dig a bit deeper it turns out to be a chicken-egg question whether the theory of sums of two squares was first or the fact that $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ has unique factorization).

Anyway, $2=(1+i)(1-i)=-i(1+i)^2$ is a factor of $(259+i)(259-i)$, so we expect $259+i$ to be divisibile by $1+i$. A basic complex division shows that this is true:
$$
\frac{259+i}{1+i}=\frac{(259+i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}=\frac{260-258i}2=130-129i.
$$
That went smoothly, we now know that
$$
17\cdot1973=130^2+129^2.
$$
Let's get rid of that $17$. It is the product $17=(4+i)(4-i)$. Those factors are primes of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ because their norms are primes of $\Bbb{Z}$.
Again we expect $130-129i$ to be divisible by one of them. Let's check
$$
\frac{130-129i}{4-i}=\frac{(130-129i)(4+i)}{(4-i)(4+i)}=\frac{649}{17}-\frac{386}{17}i.
$$
This didn't work. So we need to try the other prime of norm $17$:
$$
\frac{130-129i}{4+i}=\frac{(130-129i)(4-i)}{(4+i)(4-i)}=\frac{391-646i}{17}=23-38i.
$$

That's better!

Answer (score 3):

consider the complex number $z = (3+5i)$

$|z| = \sqrt {34}$

Since $1973$ is a prime number and $1973 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

There exists a complex number $w$ such that $|w| = \sqrt {1973}$

and $|zw|^2 = 34\cdot 1973$

If $zw = 1+259i$
then $z\bar w$ will yield $a+bi$ such that $a^2 + b^2  = 1^2 + 259^2$

let $w = x+iy$

$3x - 5y = 1\\
5x + 3y = 259\\
34x = 1298$

We might need to fiddle with the conjugates...assume $(3+5i)(x+iy) = 1 - 259i$

$3x - 5y = 1\\
5x + 3y = -259\\
34x = -1292\\
x = -38\\
y = -23$

Comment: Well since we are squaring, we can simply let $x$ and $y$ be positive, even though we derive that they are negative. $(+1)$ though :)